Unable to Fetch Network Fee for Solana Transactions - How to Fix?
I'm encountering an issue when trying to estimate the network fee for my Solana transactions. I get an error message saying: "There was a problem estimating the fee for this transaction. It may fail." Additionally, the network fee field displays "Couldn't fetch network fee".
I've tried refreshing my wallet and ensuring my internet connection is stable, but the problem persists.
Has anyone experienced this issue before, and what are some potential solutions? Could this be related to the Solana network itself, or is it more likely to be an issue with the wallet or DApp I'm using?
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!


No one cant help :(
